# Output of clustalo on (1.2.1) on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to align the following 8 sequences using clustalo on ubuntu terminal using the following command. But I am not getting the right output.

```
clustalo -i sequence.fasta -o output.clu
```

My input file is`sequence.fasta` with 8 sequences I downloaded from BLAST

My output file `output.clu`

[image]

The output I was hoping for [`outputOnline.clustal`](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web/toolresult.ebi?jobId=clustalo-I20160605-085102-0317-44529748-oy)

Also I would appreciate if some can tell me how to share this kind of data in a question because obviously the way I have done is doesnot seem appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the [output format](http://www.clustal.org/omega/README) with the `outfmt` flag.

```
clustalo -i sequence.fasta -o output.clu -outfmt=clu
```

should give you the desired output.

---

How to share data?

Try using an abbreviated example which people can copy&paste, for longer data you could use something like http://pastebin.com/ but the URL might expire.

> > gi|1709777|sp|P51780.1|PRIO_TRIVU MGKIQLGYWILVLFIVTWSDLGLCKKPKPRPGGGWNSGGSNRYPGQPGSPGGNRYPGWGHPQGGGTNWGQPHPGGSNWGQPHPGGSSWGQPHGGSNWGQGGYNKWKPDKPKT
> >
> > gi|1709773|sp|P52114.1|PRIO_MUSPF MVKSHIGSWLLVLFVATWSDIGFCKKRPKPGGGWNTGGSRYPGQGSPGGNRYPPQGGGGWGQPHGGGWGQPHGGGWGQPHGGGWGQPHGGGGWGQGGGSHGQWGKPSKPKT
> >
> > gi|1709774|sp|P49927.1|PRIO_PIG MVKSHIGGWILVLFVAAWSDIGLCKKRPKPGGGWNTGGSRYPGQGSPGGNRYPPQGGGGWGQPHGGGWGQPHGGGWGQPHGGGWGQPHGGGGWGQGGGSHGQWNKPSKPKT